# Dell Windows 7 dual boots with Fedora Linux - removal of GRUB boot loader

Tags: windows, boot, grub, restore

The Dell laptop I have comes with pre-installed Windows 7. Later, I installed Fedora 17.

Now, I'd like to get rid of Fedora 17 and boot normally from my Windows 7 as I did before.

I do not have the installation discs for Windows 7.  Is it possible to restore the boot loader from Windows 7 itself without installing any additional programs?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove your Fedora 17, you will be left with a broken GRUB.

AFAIK, it is not possible to restore your MBR directly from your Windows Installation. However, what you can do is, download [Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/index.htm) and boot using it.
Once you hit the GUI on it, under `Programs > Disk Tools > Partition` you will find `MBRWizard` and `MBRFix` use these to create a new MBR for your system.

Alternatively you could download a vanilla Windows ISO from Microsoft.com directly and boot using it. When booting, press `r` to reach the Recovery Console. On it type, `fixmbr` to recreate the MBR for your system.